# Giant realistic Prototaxites like fungi in a hot climate

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, biology, flora, fungi

My planet is very similar to earth around 359 to 299 million years ago. years ago. It’s mostly covered in deserts, jungles, swamps, temperate forests, and their variants.

(The Carboniferous period)

The hottest area of my planet is a hot steppe, dry forest, and a few swamps and temperate jungles. With low humidity and high temperature. I was wondering if fungus like [Prototaxites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototaxites) could grow in this type of biome. Think a cross between Madagascar and the Australian outback.

If Prototaxites can’t grow in this type of environment or if you know anything about how fungi performs in different climates please suggest types of biomes they can grow in.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please make yourself familiar with our policies by visiting the [help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is ongoing debate as to exactly how to classify [Prototaxites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototaxites) as the evidence suggests that it may be either a [true fungus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fungus) or a symbiotic [lichen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lichen). This is quite important when we consider this question because fungi are far more sensitive to their growth environment than lichens. A giant lichen similar to Prototaxites probably could survive in the rather hot, dry environment of Australia or Madagascar with minimal competition and few creature to eat it. Lichens are hardy enough that they manage to survive in the [McMurdo Dry Valleys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McMurdo_Dry_Valleys) Australia is paradisaical by comparison. A giant true fungus would be restricted to wetter areas like forests and swamps where they can be sheltered from heat and direct sunlight and have access to large volumes of the organic matter they depend on for sustenance.